# how to delete all lines that match a pattern asking permission in vi

Tags: vim, vi

Hello I'm new with vi and i have a problem making vi ask me the permission to delete all line with a pattern. My file looks like this:

```
SEQRES   1 A   46  GLY SER GLU ALA ARG GLU CYS VAL ASN CYS GLY ALA THR
SEQRES   2 A   46  ALA THR PRO LEU TRP ARG ARG ASP ARG THR GLY HIS TYR
SEQRES   3 A   46  LEU CYS ASN ALA CYS GLY LEU TYR HIS LYS MET ASN GLY
SEQRES   4 A   46  GLN ASN ARG PRO LEU ILE ARG
```

I want to delete all the lines that contain the string 'GLY'

This is what i came up to:

```
:g/GLY/cd
```

but it's definitely wrong

Comment: How about `:g/GLY/d`?

Comment: it doesn't ask for permission

Comment: plus +1 for doing genetic engineering with vim!!!

Comment: @ErichBSchulz that isn't what the +1 is for

Comment: I think anyone doing genetic engineering using vim deserves a plus one! because, clearly, vim can do anything!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the `:substitute` command has the `c`onfirm flag. However, if you use a  regular expression that matches the entire line (including the trailing newline), you can use that to delete entire lines, with confirmation:

```
:%s/.*GLY.*\n//c
```

Alternatively, you could build your own confirmation into `:global`; here's a simple one that you have to answer with either <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>Esc</kbd>:

```
:g/GLY/if confirm('Delete: ' . getline('.')) | delete _ | endif
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use the power of replace :%s]
To confirm delete all lines containing vim,
:g/vim/s/.*//gc [This confirm-replace all matching lines with blanks]
:g/^$/d         [This deletes all the blank lines]

Bonus: To confirm delete all lines that 'begin' with vim,
:g/^vim/s/.*//gc
:g/^$/d